# on button click show nex image

Tags: javascript

I want to pull image from local folder on button click, for which I have created a array with images names, and display it in the `<div>`. 
Here is code example.

```
<div id="slider"></div>
<button class="btn"></button>

var img = document.createElement('IMG');
img.setAttribute('src', 'img/' + images + ".jpg");
var images = ['photo0', 'photo1', 'photo2'];//photo0.jpg,photo1.jpg,photo2.jpg are images in folder with path img/
var btn = document.querySelecotr('.btn'); //button element with onclick function
var slider = document.getElementById('slider'); //div element in which imgs will be displayed
var i = 0;
slider.appendChild(images[i]);
if (i < images.length)
    i++;
else{
    i=0;
}
slider.appendChild(images[i]);
```

Comment: What are the objects in `var images = [photo0, photo1, photo2];` Please use the `<>` button and lorem pixel to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what you need, i quoted your images name, and made a `for` loop to loop through images names, and then created element, added attribute of image path (src), and then appended child to a slider.

```js
function add_images_to_slider(){
  var images = ["photo0", "photo1", "photo2"];
  var slider = document.getElementById('slider');
  for(var i=0; i<images.length; i++) {
      var img = document.createElement('img');
       img.setAttribute('src', 'img/' + images[i] + ".jpg");
       slider.appendChild(img);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="slider"></div>
<button id="btn" onclick="add_images_to_slider();">click me</button>
```

If you need one image per click, here is solution:

```js
function add_images_to_slider(){
  var images = ["photo0", "photo1", "photo2"];
  var slider = document.getElementById('slider');
  if (slider.getElementsByTagName('img')[0] !== undefined) slider.removeChild(slider.getElementsByTagName('img')[0]);
  if (typeof add_images_to_slider.st_i == 'undefined') add_images_to_slider.st_i=0;
  
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.setAttribute('src', 'img/' + images[add_images_to_slider.st_i] + ".jpg");
  slider.appendChild(img);
  
  if (add_images_to_slider.st_i < images.length-1) add_images_to_slider.st_i++;
  else add_images_to_slider.st_i = 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider"></div>
<button id="btn" onclick="add_images_to_slider();">click me</button>
```

In the second solution i created a static variable at function, which increment untill reached the total of images in array, then restart it self.

*EDITED*:
I've just appended removing last image from slider, by adding this code:

```
if (slider.getElementsByTagName('img')[0] !== undefined) slider.removeChild(slider.getElementsByTagName('img')[0]);
```

Comment: This adds 3 images for every click. But we don't know what OP wants after that.

Comment: So he needs one image per click?

Comment: Not sure, the problem is not well described. For what we know, this may be the correct answer (it solves the problem of not being able to add images). I upvoted.

Comment: This solves the problem of adding photos but i want to add one photo per click

Comment: I've added second solution

Comment: second solution works but i want new image to replace previous

Comment: I've added removing the image that was there before.